# How do I change the background color of a material design in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

```
        <Button
            Style="{ StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}"
            Height="40"
            materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="20"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            Margin="0,0,15,0"
            Command="{Binding UpdateSWCmd}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsSWAvailable, Converter={vc:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSWHeader, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Button>
```

I want to be able change the background of the button to Orange after I click it, but still keep the rest of the styling. How do I this?

Comment: What do you mean by _after I click_? Do you mean the _Pressed_ state or that the button background should be changed permanently once the button was clicked? Should its color never be reset then?

Comment: The button's background color should permanently once the button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

add name to button and change color onclick on code behind

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"

            Style="{ StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}"
            Height="40"
            materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="20"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            Margin="0,0,15,0"
            Command="{Binding UpdateSWCmd}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsSWAvailable, Converter={vc:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSWHeader, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Button>

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MyButton.BackgroundColor= Color.White;
        }
```